# Sparsity reduction

Tags: python, optimization, pyspark, sparse-matrix, recommendation-engine

I have to factorize a big sparse matrix ( 6.5mln rows representing users* 6.5mln columns representing items) to find users and items latent vectors. I chose the als algorithm in spark framework(pyspark).
To boost the quality I have to reduce the sparsity of my matrix till 98%. (current value is 99.99% because I have inly 356mln of filled entries).
I can do it by dropping rows or columns, but I must find the optimal solution maximizing number of rows(users).
The main problem is that I must find some subsets of users and items sets, and dropping some row can drop some columns and vice versa, the second problem is that function that evaluates sparsity is not linear.
Which way I can solve this problem? which libraries in python can help me with it? 
Thank you.

Comment: Can you be more formal and precise? I don't get your task (and imho i think i understand MF). Also your numbers don't add up (imho) and a change from 99.99% to 98% sounds like increasing density / descreasing sparsity to me. And what should dropping cols or rows do? This leads to users or items which are not represented anymore. What lead to the decision of using ALS (compared to SG or co.)? In worst-case, and that would not be unusual, is your sparsity-task harder than the core-task of MF after all.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.

Comment: 1. Why don't add up? (6.5e6 ^2 - 365e6)/6.5e6 ^2 = 0.9999, target = 0.98
2. Yes, I want to reduce sparsity, increasing density.
3. Yes, I mentioned that dropping cols may lead to that some users will dissappear in final matrix, and vise versa. I have no other options except dropping rows and cols.
4. I chose ALS, why not? is there any problem with it in my case?
5. I dont know if this problem harder than MF problem^ beacuse I dont know how to solve it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a combinatorial problem. There is no easy way to drop an optimal set of columns to achieve max number of users while reducing sparsity. A formal approach would be to formulate it as a mixed-integer program. Consider the following 0-1 matrix, derived from your original matrix C.

```
A(i,j) = 1 if C(i,j) is nonzero, 
A(i,j) = 0 if C(i,j) is zero
```

Parameters:

```
M : a sufficiently big numeric value, e.g. number of columns of A (NCOLS)
N : total number of nonzeros in C (aka in A)
```

Decision vars are

```
x(j) : 0 or 1  implying whether column j is dropped or not
nr(i): number of nonzeros covered in row i
y(i) : 0 or 1 implying whether row i is dropped or not
```

Constraints:

```
A(i,:) x  = nr(i)         for i = 1..NROWS
nr(i)    <= y(i) * M      for i = 1..NROWS
@sum(nr(i)) + e = 0.98 * N  # explicit slack 'e' to be penalized in the objective
y(i) and x(j) are 0-1 variables (binary variables) for i,j
```

Objective:

```
maximize @sum(y(i)) - N.e
```

Such a model would be extremely difficult to solve as an integer model. However, barrier methods should be able to solve the linear programming relaxations (LP) Possible solvers are Coin/CLP (open-source), Lindo (commercial) etc... It may then be possible to use the LP solution to compute approximate integer solutions by simple rounding.

In the end, you will definitely require an iterative approach which will require solving MF problem several times each time factoring a different submatrix of C, computed with above approach, until you are satisfied with the solution.

Comment: I didnt solve this problem yet, but your answer helped a lot. Thank you